# In place deletion of Golang slice elements

Tags: go, slice, in-place

I want to delete elements from a collection in an in-place manner. 
Consider the following snippet:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Ints []int

func (xs Ints) Filter() {
    for i := 0; i < len(xs); i++ {
        if xs[i]%2 == 0 { // Or some other filtering function
             xs = append(xs[:i], xs[i+1:]...)
        }
        fmt.Printf("i %+v\n", i)
        fmt.Printf("xs %+v\n", xs)
    }
}

func main() {
    a := Ints([]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10})

    fmt.Printf("initial a %+v\n", a)

    a.Filter()

    fmt.Printf("final a %+v\n", a)
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/1nL6Il2Gf1

The surprising result is: `final a [1 3 5 7 9 10 10 10 10 10]`

I wonder how to do this. I'm pretty sure the receiver needs to be a pointer to `Ints`. But that messes up the code somewhat (adding `*xs` everywhere possibly with brackets) but more importantly it yields the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it by moving elements, then resizing the slice, and using a pointer. Something like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Ints []int

func (xs *Ints) Filter() {
    filterPos := 0
    for i := 0; i < len(*xs); i++ {
        if (*xs)[i]%2 == 0 { // Or some other filtering function
             (*xs)[filterPos] = (*xs)[i]
         filterPos++
        }
    }
    (*xs) = (*xs)[:filterPos]
}

func main() {
    a := Ints([]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10})

    fmt.Printf("initial a %+v\n", a)

    a.Filter()

    fmt.Printf("final a %+v\n", a)
}
```

Comment: Just a tiny recommendation, use `(*xs) = (*xs)[:filterPos:filterPos]` instead to trim the slice and free the extra memory, it could be a decent amount of memory with bigger objects.

Comment: @OneOfOne true, it depends if you're optimizing for speed or memory. I'd actually just create a new slice and keep everything immutable, unless this was a huge chunk of memory.

Comment: @OneOfOne I wonder how that's implemented in the runtime (no time to read it...). Does it create a new underlying memory buffer or call realloc on it? The second option is much much faster but might result in memory fragmentation.

Comment: I'm not actually sure, but we know it doesn't create a new array because it's the same address.

Comment: What about the solution @chendesheng? It seems less complex. It just replaces the pointer. But that not true in-place is it? Does that matter?

Comment: Technically they are the same, it's just saving the casting to (*xs) and makes the code less ugly.  @chendesheng didn't deal with the internal re-slicing in your original code, which I think will be very inefficient (but it's worth a benchmark!)

Comment: @OneOfOne from diving into the runtime code, I'm not sure if the 2 approaches to reslicing will result in different behavior, or will trigger a memory copy anyway.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer I'm guessing it called `realloc` to trim, because judging by http://play.golang.org/p/4xkP9vLTFk the underlying array doesn't change at all, that's kinda cool, I didn't know that.

Comment: I've benchmarked all approaches, and it actually appears that re-slicing like in the original code is MUCH faster (X2)! I guess it's because then the copying is done by low level C and not Go itself.

Comment: Oh, sorry sorry, my bad, the benchmark had a bug. The answer's approach is ~200 times faster :)

Answer (score 1):

You must use pointer here. If you don't like adding *xs every where just use a temp variable to do all operations then set it back. Here is the code http://play.golang.org/p/eAFkV3Lwh6

Answer (score 1):

Your code was almost right.

The first bug is that you need to avoid doing `i++` when you're deleting an element, otherwise the `i++` skips over the next, unread element. That's why I've put it in the `else` clause.

The second bug is that `xs` is a local variable of the `Filter` function, so if you change what it points to (with `xs = ...`) that does not change what `a` points to inside `main`. You can solve this issue by making it a pointer (`*xs` as others have posted) or by returning the new filtered slice, as I've done below.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Ints []int

func (xs Ints) Filtered() Ints {
    for i := 0; i < len(xs); {
        if xs[i]%2 == 0 {
            xs = append(xs[:i], xs[i+1:]...)
        } else {
            i++
        }
    }
    return xs
}

func main() {
    a := Ints([]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10})
    b := a.Filtered()
    fmt.Println(b)
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/Nre7w4KQ78